# Mockito:calling method inside method

Tags: mockito

I have following class and method inside it

```
public class A extends B implements C{


public void validateTicketGrantingTicket(final TicketGrantingTicket ticketGrantingTicket) throws InvalidTicketException {

    if (ticketGrantingTicket != null)
    {
        if (!ticketGrantingTicket.getHostDomain().equalsIgnoreCase(getServerName()))
        {
            throw new InvalidTicketException();
        }
    }
}


public String getServerName()
{
    String serverName = "";
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    if (request != null)
    {
        serverName = request.getServerName().toLowerCase();
    }

    return serverName;
}
}
```

Now I am writing ATest class and mocking class A.

```
public class ATest {
private A a;

@Before
public void init(){

    A = mock(A.class);

    when(A.getServerName()).thenReturn("phoenix.edu.abc");      
}


@Test
public void validateTicketGrantingTicketTest() throws  InvalidTicketException{  
    a = new A();
    ticketGrantingTicket = new   
    TicketGrantingTicketImpl("test",testUtils.getAuthentication(), new 
    NeverExpiresExpirationPolicy());

    a.validateTicketGrantingTicket(ticketGrantingTicket);
}
```

Mock object is giving me null pointer exception for getServerName() method instead of string "phoenix.edu.abc"

Answer (score 7):

By calling `a = new A();` in your test method, you create a new instance of A and the reference to the mocked A instance that was created in the `init()` method will be lost. Consequently, A's "real" implementation of `getServerName()` method will called and not the one that you have mocked.

Another problem that you have is that you are trying to both mock and test the same class simultaneously. On the one hand you are testing `validateTicketGrantingTicket()`, but at the same time you are mocking `getServerName()`. You *can* get around this problem by using [spy()](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy%28T%29) rather than `mock()`, but it is better to refactor the code into two separate classes.

Comment: Yeah prefer the 2 class refactoring, it is better to have classes with diferent responsabilities, than classes that have multiple reponsabilities, (it leads to unmaintainable code)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it not be a good idea to move the method getServerName to a different class so that it can be re-used elsewhere?  This will make it easy to test this scenario.

As matsev said, you are also trying to mock the class under test, which is not a right practice.  This can be used in exceptional situations, as pointed out by him, using `spy()`.  Even mockito introduced this feature in its later releases but strongly suggests its users to limit the use of `spy()`.

If you move the method to a new class, you can easily mock the other class and return the value which you need.

```
public class A extends B implements C{
private AUtil util;

public void validateTicketGrantingTicket(final TicketGrantingTicket ticketGrantingTicket) throws InvalidTicketException {

    if (ticketGrantingTicket != null)
    {
        String serverName = util.getServerName()
        if (!ticketGrantingTicket.getHostDomain().equalsIgnoreCase(serverName))
        {
            throw new InvalidTicketException();
        }
    }
}
}


public class AUtil {
public String getServerName()
{
    String serverName = "";
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    if (request != null)
    {
        serverName = request.getServerName().toLowerCase();
    }

    return serverName;
}
}
```

Now this can be considered a good design if we move all the utility functions to the common class from which all classes like A can reuse them.  It now has a separated concern and better testability.  You can easily mock this method without a spy.

```
public class ATest {

//cut provides a uniform naming convention-Class Under Test
private AUtil cut;

//Mock can now be created using annotations in Mockito
@Mock
AUtil mock;

@Test
public void validateTicketGrantingTicketTest() throws  InvalidTicketException{  

    cut = new A();

    ticketGrantingTicket = new   
    TicketGrantingTicketImpl("test",testUtils.getAuthentication(), new 
    NeverExpiresExpirationPolicy());

    when(mock.getServerName()).thenReturn("phoenix.edu.abc");

    a.validateTicketGrantingTicket(ticketGrantingTicket);
}
}
```

Comment: mockito does not support static method.